# Execute code when element is dragged (Jquery Draggable)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I'm using http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ to move some elements around.
However I need some code to be executed when a element is moved around (dragged).

I was thinking something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

    document.getElementById("#MyDiv").drag: function (event) {
        //execute code
    }

});
</script>
```

The code above is just an example to show how I want it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$( "#MyDiv" ).draggable({
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
 //code
}
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery-ui dragable ([example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events), [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/))

```
$( "#MyDiv" ).draggable({
  start: function() {

  },
  drag: function() {

  },
  stop: function() {

  }
});
```